# Are these files needed inside the .app file? (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, compilation

I'm very new to xCode (or compiled code in general) and I was wondering when I was looking through the .app file if all these were needed. 
For every of my classes there is a *.o; .d; .swiftdeps; ~partial.swiftdoc; ~partial.swiftmodule* file.
Some of these files also contain my working directories...
In the *Build Phases* of my app I added all my classes to *Copy Bunde Resources* (otherwise I would get a compile error), maybe that is the reason or are all these files just necessary?
Because when I was looking through over apps I did not find any of these kind of files.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: If it works then it should be fine. You probably shouldn't mess with the .app file.

Comment: Normally you don't have to mess around with the Copy Bundle Resources settings yourself. As you add new source files to your project Xcode should take care of those settings for you. Are you sure the files you describe are in the .app file, and not in the intermediate build directories?

Comment: @DuncanC When i create a new file xCode automatically adds it to the "Compile Sources" settings. If i do not add the file i get a 'Use of unresolved identifier"MyClass"' error. When i add the source file manually to "Copy Bundle Resources" it finds the Class. Same with my app icons. I had to add the assets folder to "Copy Bundle Resources" for the icons to work. And yes, it seems to be the real app. Even used "Produkt -> Archive" i get the files INSIDE the .app package. :)